# Firs order PDE ( the problem from calculus)

Tags: calculus

I've never studied PDE theory, so the problem is probably simple.
Given equtaion $f_1(x,y,z)\frac{\partial u }{\partial x} + f_2(x,y,z) \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + f_3(x,y,z)\frac{\partial u}{\partial z} = 0 $

I need to prove that the first integrals (functions which is constant on solutions)  of the system 
$\frac {\dot {x(t)}} {f_1} = \frac { \dot{y(t)}} {f_2} = \frac { \dot {z(t)}} {f_3}$

Okay, let $F(x,y,z) = const$ for $ x = x(t), y=y(t), z = z(t)$, so I write

$ \frac {dF} {dt} = \dot {x}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} + \dot {y}\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} + \dot {z}\frac{\partial F}{\partial z} = 0$
What sould I do next?

Comment: Do you miss $u$ in $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x,y,z$ are functions of $t$ and $F(x,y,z)=u(t)=cost$ is a solution. Then
$$ \frac{du}{dt}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{d t}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dt}=0.$$
Comparing this with the equation gives
$$ \frac{d x}{dt}=kf_1,\frac{dy}{dr}=kf_2,\frac{dz}{dr}=kf_3$$
where $k$ is a constant. Write $\frac{d x}{dt}=\dot{x},\frac{dy}{dr}=\dot{y},\frac{dz}{dr}=\dot{z}$ and  hence one has
$$ \frac{\dot{x}}{f_1}=\frac{\dot{y}}{f_2}=\frac{\dot{z}}{f_3}.$$

Comment: But converse is not true, who says that from this system one gets $\dot {x} = f_1$ and so on?

Comment: Just a constant coefficient